# How to display imgs or divs with diferent heights?

Tags: row, display

I have some

inside a div with the class row using Bootstrap, but I want to do what I show in the image, to have images or text, and not have all of my text display in a grid.
[image]

Because I have some text longer than others and it leaves blank space, like this
[image]

I tried to display the text like the first photo but I got the text displayed in a grid.